# how to load images in array to faster display android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, load

Hello i am running a onuithread inside a thread and it has a times and it will be changing randomly each time slower until it select 2 items from the list. my problem is that this items has pictures and my idea is to everytime the name change the picture should change but when adding the pictures it will display something like this:
Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

is there a way to load the images in the array and then in the runuithread only display them without loading them again? here in my runuithread:

```
 while (i < 400) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(i);
                    // here you check the value of getActivity() and break up if needed
                    if (getActivity() == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            start_btn.setEnabled(false);
                            Collections.shuffle(numbers);
                            Collections.shuffle(players_list);
                            player1_tv.setText(players[players_list.get(0)]);
                            player2_tv.setText(players[players_list.get(1)]);
                            group1_tv.setText(all_teams.get(numbers.get(0)));

                            player1_iv.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(pictures.get(numbers.get(0)),"drawable",con.getPackageName()));
                            group2_tv.setText(group.get(numbers.get(1)));
                            i += 30;

                            if (i > 420) {
                                start_btn.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ooops
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image can be loaded and stored as a Bitmap object. You can load Bitmap from a resource like this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), {resourceId});
```

Then you can set the image:

```
player1_iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello Anton, is the resourceId an array or resources? because loading image one over the other will give me the error about application doing too much work in UI. i need to have all the images ready and loaded outside the onuithread and then just display them one after the other in the uithread

Comment: You can load images into an array outside of the UI thread. Then use this array on the UI thread to set the bitmap for your ImageViews. Don't forget to release this array when you don't need it. Android apps are sensitive to memory consumption.

Comment: can you show me how to do this? right now i have all my images names in an array but to load them into a bitmap array how can i do that?

Comment: ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
bitmapArray.add(myBitMap); // Add a bitmap
bitmapArray.get(0); // Get first bitmap

Comment: @ElvisBoss Are your images in a "drawable" folder? You can get resource id with R.drawable.{image file name}. Then load the the image as shown in the answer.